# Multiple Url rewrite rules - got 403 on the last

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have the following rules, but when I access https://myserver/myapp/sparoute/1 I get a 403 instead of the index.html

I got this config at root of myapp:

```
   <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to API" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="api/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://internalserver/myapp/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Signalr" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="messagehub(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://internalserver/myapp/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Handle History Mode for SPA (myapp)" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The first two rules are working, but instead of returning the default index.html when rewriting to / i get a 403. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite url is relative to website. so the last action should be

`<action type="Rewrite" url="/myapp" />`

Comment: It is appreciated if you could accept your reply as answer.